# How I can add capability to download to my app

Tags: datatable, download, shinydashboard

You please image I have this app

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

my_data <- head(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(my_data)
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want people to be able to download the rendered table from my app but I don't how to add  downloading capability and download button to my app; Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server <- function(input, output){

  output[["table1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable((my_data), editable = "cell", extensions = "Buttons", 
              options = list(
                dom = "Bfrtip",
                buttons = list(
                  "csv"
                )
              ))
  })

  observeEvent(input[["table_cell_edit"]], {
    cellinfo <- input[["table_cell_edit"]]
    dat <<- editData(dat, input[["table_cell_edit"]], "table1")
  })


}
```